# Safari 7 Developer Tools Bug?

Tags: macos, safari, web-inspector

Ran into some peculiar behavior in the midst of my developing antics. I have my developer tools set to appear in a separate window - I noticed if I right-click and inspect an element, close the developer tools window, then inspect another element, the first element remains targeted in the DOM inspector.

I often inspect elements just for quick reference on a value or stylesheet location, and close the window out of habit because it crowds my limited screen space. At first this behavior was just a mild annoyance, but it's becoming maddening when I have to right-click twice on anything I want to inspect. I'm now doing this dozens of times a day - is this bug known/documented anywhere? Is there a fix for it?

I'm deeply considering switching to Chrome, but Chrome has it's own [deal-breakers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144256/stop-chrome-loading-videos-in-background-tabs) that irk me slightly more than this bug. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). It is one of the most useful tools for me as a web developer. It works in safari. And I can't say enough about it.

By the way, I'm in no way affiliated with firebug.

Comment: I would of left a comment but I do not have enough rep.